# javascript, iframe, security - Permission denied when tring to access a js function from parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, permissions

Good day to all.

I have a page that includes an iframe. In that iframe I have a script with function called test(). I need to access the function from the parent window. After asking around I got to this solution:

```
<div onclick="document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.teste();">Test</div>
```

On click the test function should be run. The problem is that I get "   Permission denied to access property test" error.

It looked like a permission error to me so I changed the file loaded in iframe permissions to 777, but without any result.

Note: The file loaded in iframe is not on the same domain.

Comment: this has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's prohibited to access pages from other domains by default, because browsers use [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). There are several workaround like using location.hash or window.name to communicate between frames. The most recent and standardized in HTML5 is postMessage-interface.
There is library for cross-browser solution http://easyxdm.net/wp/.

Comment: Ok... how do I change this? I have root access on both domains.

Comment: is this for an intranet, where you have control over all the browsers?

Comment: if this is the case, you can disable web security in some browsers. search for disabling SOP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/can-i-disable-sop-same-origin-policy-on-any-browser-for-development, but in general only ugly hacks exists, the security policies implemented on browsers are there for a reason

Comment: What if I use a subdomain for the iframe file?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is possible, cross window (frame) communication have to be at same domain, protocol and hostname. For more info see [Same origin policy for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and [Cross domain communication with iframes](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)