# javascript IFrame permissions

Tags: javascript

I know that for protection of the client you can do very little on the contentWindow and contentWindow.document property of the iframe, but what exactly *is* possible?

Edit: I should have clarified that it's cross-domain.

Comment: what exactly you want to know? Everything is possible if it's on the same domain.

Comment: @ocanal Which methods and fields I can access

Comment: You can get the URL of the document, and the size of the window, and that's it. Anything else would violate the "same origin" policy. You can find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094514/javascript-iframe-security-permission-denied-when-tring-to-access-a-js-funct

Comment: Also, here is a long but well-thought-out discussion as well as techniques outlined here: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes