# Disable Same-Origin Check in FireFox 6

Tags: firefox, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to debug an XMPP application I'm building in javascript.  I want to use FireBug because I think it works really well as far as javascript debuggers go.  The problem I'm having is an XSS issue.  The XMPP server we're using is located on another machine an I need to connect to it.

I can debug no problem in Chrome using the --disable-web-security flag when opening the application.  I just can't seem to find the Firefox equivalent (if there even is one).  Every thing I'm finding on the issue is years old targeting ancient versions of Firefox.

I was hoping it would be a config value in about:config or at least an extension I could install but I'm coming up blank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable SOP (Same Origin Policy) on any browser for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/can-i-disable-sop-same-origin-policy-on-any-browser-for-development)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [simple one-button Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forcecors/) that adds the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers to every request. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this, as long as there is a `about:config` in FireFox 6 with this property

```
about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false
```