# Disable Chrome Same Origin Policy for a specific domain

Tags: google-chrome, same-origin-policy, cors

Is it possible to modify the same origin policy in Chrome?

I plan to allow the specific domain `foo.com` to access an iframe with a different origin. The idea is to have a "login machine" which knows the login data and where to put it. I know about CORS but it's not the solution because I don't have access to some of the different origins to set the custom header.

I know there are many other solutions to build a "login machine" :)
I tried selenium, and I tried a chrome browser extension. but it wasn't that good and the user experience was bad.

I like Firefox's `enablePrivilege` but it isnt supported in newer versions.

Is it a lack of functionality if I can't disable-web-security for a specific domain?

best regards

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/can-i-disable-sop-same-origin-policy-on-any-browser-for-development

Comment: Also, Chrome extensions can bypass the same-origin policy if they have the domain in their manifest.json file.