# How to call a on a self hosted servlet from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet that posts data as an xml page.I made it in Eclipse IDE for Java EE and host it on a Tomcat server. The servlet is hosted on http://localhost:8080/Checkers/CheckersServlet. I can open that url in firefox and it loads the xml fine. How do I call on the servlet from the ajax code?

I think it's supposed to be something like the code below, but that does not work for me. (where displayResult(req) is a custom function that does what I want with the xml received from the servlet). I have confirmed through debugging that the problem is not receiving any xml from the servlet.

Do I need to make one of these web.xml files? Or is that handled by Eclipse when I click "new Servlet"

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        if(req.readyState == 4)
        {
            displayResult(req);

        }
    }
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/Checkers/CheckersServlet"; 
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your servlet is accessible via web browser or `curl`, the problem is on the client side.

Where are you hosting the JavaScript, i.e. what is the URL of the page that runs this JavaScript code? If it is not `localhost:8080`, you are unfortunately experiencing [same-origin-policy](/questions/tagged/same-origin-policy). To verify that please add the code snippet described in [Can I disable SOP (Same Origin Policy) on any browser for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330427) - it should work after you accept the change in Firefox.

The easiest correct solution is to place your `js` file somewhere in Eclipse and deploy it Tomcat as well so that it is available under `localhost:8080/Checkers/some-file.js` (same domain).

Comment: I am not hosting the javascript, it's just directly defined in my ajax code. I'll look for a tutorial on hosting javascipt code. Here is a more detailed post I made earlier before I figured out exactly what my problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656156/getelementsbytagname-returning-an-empty-list-when-used-on-responcetext-responc

Comment: I do not know how to host the javascript file on my server. I added it to the checkers project, but when I click run on the checkers project name and not just on the servlet it asks if I would like to run on server, or as a java applet or java application. If I choose run on server it doesn't seem to work if I try to reference it, the script never loads and the code breaks.